# JavaScript Функция и console.log()

Tags: javascript

Почему два подобных экземпляра кода, которые, по логике, должны иметь одинаковые исходные результаты, дают разные исходные результаты?

```
function rectangleArea(width, height) {
 console.log(width * height);
}

rectangleArea(5, 7) 
//Output 35
```

и

```
function rectangleArea(width, height) {
 console.log(width * height);
}

console.log(rectangleArea(5, 7))
// prints 35 и undefined
```

Comment: почему ты решила, что они должны иметь одинаковые результаты? и какие именно ты ожидаешь одинаковости?

Comment: у вас функция ничего не возвращает, поэтому undefined

Comment: ожидаю везде 35. В первом варианте понятно, просто вызываю функцию, а во втором хочу что бы результат вывелся благодаря методу console.log

Comment: В функцию добавьте `return width * height` и будет вам счастье )

Comment: это понятно. просто стало интересно почему я не могу воспользоваться console.log вместо return

Comment: @MarynaSaid а почему вы не пользуетесь ложкой вместо ножа, чтобы порезать колбасу или мясо?

Comment: Потому что console.log() это не return.

Answer (score 7):

Функция, которая не возвращает ничего, на самом деле по умолчанию возвращает undefined. Так что во втором примере консоль в виде возвращаемого значения получает его и выводит.

Если надо результат напечатать в консоли, то надо этот результат вернуть из функции. А этим занимается ключевое слово `return` (что  в переводе с английского будет "вернуть"), а не `console.log`